# Php highlight search terms using preg_replace - character encoding issues

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-replace

Hy guys, I need to highlight some searched words, in the result, and i was thinking to use pre_replace, and it works just fine, until i use accented characters.

So this is my code:

```
preg_replace("/(?<!\[)(\b{$search}\b)(?!\])/i", $replace, $string);
```

And if I'm looking for the word "mokus", it finds it, but leaves out "mókus",

The same thing happens the other way around.

And ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have your encoding on UTF-8 ? If not try to put this on the top of the code `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: @S.Visser thanks but that's not the problem, thats allready set

Comment: Well, "mókus" is not the same as "mokus". Regular expressions aren't simply locale aware by default. You'd need to create the regex `m[oó]kus` for that to work.

Comment: @deceze thanks, i somehow tought that would work just the same, but do you got any ideas how could i do this? i mean this was just an example but people can search anything on the site

Comment: I'm sorry misunderstood the question. I think its pretty tricky to do `normalize` special chars with reqular expressions, but PHP has an class called normalize, maybe you can work whit that class. http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to research the term Accent Folding.

Here's a good [article](http://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete) to understand the problem, the proposed solutions are in Javascript but you can translate the logic to PHP